# Cakephp How to constrain $this->set() to a subset of model data with find()

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-model

I'm trying to create a single, one-off page that will combine information from several models. This is the code I'm trying to use:

```
public function index() {
    $this->loadModel('people');
    $this->people->find('all', array(
                                    'order'=>'people.last_name ASC',
                                    'conditions' => array(
                                                        'People.member =' => '1',
                                                        ),
                                    ));
    $this->set('people', $this->paginate('people') );
    }
```

But it seems that my call to `find()` has no impact on `$this->set()`, and I don't understand why.

Comment: I assume that this is in your PeopleController, which means that you don't have to load the model. Your model name should be Person (singular of People). Also, check out this link for information on how to use Paginate http://book.cakephp.org/view/1232/Controller-Setup

Comment: No, it's in an independent controller—a 'dashboard' controller; basically, I need ostensibly static pages that use various model data, such a controller lets me generate one-off pages with access to a variety of model data. But either way, I don't understand how loading the model impacts the relationship between `find()` and `set`

Comment: var_dump your `find`, then var_dump your `$this->paginate('people')` and you'll see the difference. `$this->set()` saves a variable (in your case, the result of *$this->paginate('people')*) for use inside a view template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function index() {
    $this->loadModel('people');
    $findPeople = $this->people->find('all', array(
                                    'order'=>'people.last_name ASC',
                                    'conditions' => array(
                                                        'People.member =' => '1',
                                                        ),
                                    ));
    $this->set('people', $findPeople);
    }
```

I think paginate will ignore your conditions unless you put the conditions in the paginate...